# Why functions are described as block scoped

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading [this book on ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#ch_variables) and there is the following:

> Function declarations…
>
> - are block-scoped, like let.
> - create properties in the global object
>     (while in global scope), like var.
> - are hoisted: independently of where
>     a function declaration is mentioned in its scope, it is always created
>     at the beginning of the scope.

AFAIK, functions have always been function scoped. I thought something might have changed in ES6, but nope:

```
function a() {
    if (true) {
        // defined inside the block and is hoisted to the top of that block
        z();
        function z() { console.log ('z')}
    }

    z();
}

// but is also hoisted to the function scope
a(); // works OK
```

Actually, they seem to be block scoped:

```
function a() {
    if (false) {
        // defined inside the block and is hoisted to the top of that block
        z();
        function z() { console.log ('z')}
    }

    z(); // error
}
```

So has it changed in ES6?

Comment: I think that the book uses the (existing) function declaration as example to explain how `let` fits into the picture.

Comment: That's because you're executing it in loose mode. In strict mode it should be as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AFAIK, functions have always been function scoped. I thought something might have changed in ES6

It did: Prior to ES2015, the spec didn't cover functions declared within blocks at all. Supporting them was an allowed extension, but not part of the spec.

As a result, the spec has to jump through hoops, particularly in loose mode on browsers.

In *strict* mode, you'll find on a compliant engine that function declarations are indeed block-scoped:

```js
"use strict";

function test() {
  if (true) {
    function foo() {
      console.log("foo called");
    }
  }
  try {
    foo(); // ReferenceError
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error: " + String(e));
  }
}
test();
```

On a compliant JavaScript engine (such as V8 in any recent version of Chrome, or SpiderMonkey in any recent version of Firefox), you'll get a `ReferenceError` on the above.

Comment: @TJCrowder On firefox I get this SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function

Comment: @Eineki: That must be a fairly old version of Firefox ("old" being a fairly relative term in ES2015-support-land :-) ). I get the expected `ReferenceError` in Firefox v50.1.0.